# How to stop enter key from reloading page in a form in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, enter

I have a search bar with a button that searches for stuff on another site. I got it to function correctly (it searches on the other site in a new tab) but anytime I click enter in the search bar, the page I'm on reloads. At first it reloaded from pressing enter and clicking search, then I changed the input type to button rather than submit. This took care of reloading when clicking on the button, but when the enter key is pressed the page reloads. Also, it only reloads if the search bar is clicked, not just at all times. The search bar has to be selected for the enter key to reload the page.

html:

```
<div id="search-3" class="widget widget_search">
    <h3 align="center">Search the other site!</h3>
    <form method="post" name="searchform" id="searchform">

      <span class="searching">
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
      </span>
      <input class="submit" type="button" Onclick="SearchBlog();" value="Search" />

    </form>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function SearchBlog()
{
    var searchQuery = document.searchform.s.value;
    if(searchQuery != ""){
        var destination = "website.com/s" + searchQuery;
        window.open(destination, "_blank");
    }
}
```

I want to be able to use the enter key to search but I don't want it to reload the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because you are submitting to a page that isn't there.

Use `onsubmit` in your `<form>` declaration instead:

```
<form method="POST" name="searchform" id="searchform" onsubmit="SearchBlog();">
   ...
</form>
```

Then make sure you `return false;` in your SearchBlog() function. And you should be good to go.

Comment: This way, you can submit your form with the desired result using either the click on the submit button/image or pressing enter within the form. This is better for the user experience!

Comment: So I should get rid of    method="POST" name="searchform" id="searchform"    and use    onsubmit="SearchBlog();    instead?

Comment: No, I would leave all that in place. Ideally, make it so that it degrades gracefully if your user does not have Javascript enabled. But, add the `onsubmit="SearchBlog();"` though.

Comment: Thank you! That pretty much worked, however there is still a reload but it takes less than half a second. This is only noticed when the search bar is blank. I already have the if statement set up to stop the script from opening a new tab if the search bar is empty, but can I make the page not reload at all if the search bar is empty? And to specify, I put the return false; inside and outside the if statement in my javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input class="submit" type="button" Onclick="return SearchBlog();" value="Search" />
```

And

```
function SearchBlog()
{
    var searchQuery = document.searchform.s.value;
    if(searchQuery != ""){
        var destination = "website.com/s" + searchQuery;
        window.open(destination, "_blank");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: maybe because it's "OnClick"